# Undefined behavior (unrealiable segfaults) with SDL2 wrapper classes

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 with C++ (compiling with g++ and using valgrind to debug some stuff) and right now I'm using wrapper classes to set up destructors and constructors for Renderers, Windows, etc. My program is cuurently crashes and segfaults, but only sometimes. It doesn't most of the time, but it could very well be due to uninitialized variables. Here's what valgrind says:

```
==227== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==227==    at 0xEA89BF2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
==227==    by 0xEA89CB3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
==227==    by 0x4E9A920: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0)
==227==    by 0x4E9A978: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0)
==227==    by 0x4E9BA62: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0)
==227==    by 0x4E8FE12: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0)
==227==    by 0x4032E9: game::Renderer::init() (Renderer.cpp:13)
==227==    by 0x4033CA: game::Renderer::Renderer(SDL_Window*&) (Renderer.cpp:31)
==227==    by 0x401AA2: game::Environment::Environment() (Environment.cpp:11)
==227==    by 0x4015D0: main (source.cpp:15)
==227==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==227==    at 0x4E9A7A0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0)
```

Here's the renderer functions in question:

```
namespace game {
        //init function that sets up the renderer. It is basically so all of my constructors don't use the same
        //code.
        void Renderer::init() {
                if (window != NULL) {
                        theRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 
SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
                        if (theRenderer == NULL) {
                                cout << "Renderer could not be created: " << 
SDL_GetError() << endl;
                        }
                        else {
                                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (theRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                        }
                }
        }

        //parameterized constructor that takes a reference to an SDL_Window pointer
        //and sets up the renderer for that window
        Renderer::Renderer(SDL_Window*& initWindow): theRenderer(NULL), window(initWindow) {
                this->init();
        }


}
```

And the window constructor that should initialize it:

```
namespace game {

//Default constructor that sets up the window to be rendered to
Window::Window(): theWindow(NULL) {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
                cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }
        else {
                this->theWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Platformer", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
                if(theWindow == NULL) {
                        cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: "
                                << SDL_GetError() << endl;
                }
        }
}



}
```

I've searched around, but can't find anything related to this specific error. Does anyone see where my uninitialized variable is?

Comment: I'm wondering what the heck a *reliable* segfault could be :-)

Comment: So which line is line 13? @paxdiablo one that happens every time? `*(int*)NULL = 0;` is a pretty reliable segfault in that I've never seen it not segfault, even though it theoreticaly might not (because of undefined behaviour). `raise(SIGSEGV)` is even more reliable but it's debatable whether it's actually a segfault.

Comment: Where is the pointer passed to `Renderer`'s constructor initialized?

Comment: @immibis, good point but you've totally ruined my attempted humour. Which my wife tells me rather often is little more *than* an attempt :-) FWIW (and from very vague memory), HPUX had a mode where dereferencing 0 would always gives you 0, and trying to store something there would basically do nothing.

Comment: Can you reproduce a crash in debugger or at least save coredump upon crash and inspect it in debugger later? Stacktrace and variable values are likely to provide some insight.

Comment: @immibis What if I tell you clang doesn't segfault on `*(int*)0 = 0;`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72c8c54d9a0dcb4a

Comment: Wwell, I tried to repicate it in a debugger, but my gdb in Windows Linux subsystem doesn't seem to like it. Although my program doesn't seem to actually segfault anymore; hopefully it doesn't randomly start again.